# assets compilation in Canvas LMS on ubuntu

Tags: compilation, npm, assets, node-gyp, canvas-lms

I am trying to setup Canvas-LMS on my system but during assets compilation I am facing some problems. These are my node versions:

- node-gyp -v v3.0.3
- node -v v4.2.1
- npm -v
  2.10.1

This is my console screen while I am trying to compile my assets.

```
nsgill@STPL-IND-PAGRAWAL:~/projects/canvas-lms$ bundle exec rake canvas:compile_assets --trace
** Invoke canvas:compile_assets (first_time)
** Execute canvas:compile_assets
--> Starting: 'Making sure node_modules are up to date'
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/node_modules/concat-stream/package.json'
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/node_modules/load-json-file/package.json'
--> Finished: 'Making sure node_modules are up to date' in 122.05152510900007
--> Starting: 'compile css (including custom brands)'
no sass changes detected
--> Finished: 'compile css (including custom brands)' in 1.5083165989999543
working in 2 processes
--> Starting: 'compile coffee, js 18n, and run r.js optimizer'
--> Starting: 'js:generate'
** Invoke js:generate (first_time)
** Execute js:generate
--> Starting: 'css:styleguide'
** Invoke css:styleguide (first_time)
** Execute css:styleguide
--> creating styleguide
** Invoke js:build_client_apps (first_time)
** Execute js:build_client_apps
Building client app 'canvas_quizzes'
Running 'npm install'...
npm WARN EPEERINVALID react@0.10.0 requires a peer of envify@~1.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON canvas_quizzes@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON canvas_quizzes@1.0.0 No license field.
Running 'npm run build'...
--> Finished: 'css:styleguide' in 7.147470806999991
--> Starting: 'Generate documentation [yardoc]'
** Invoke doc:api (first_time)
** Execute doc:api
[error]: Unhandled exception in YARD::Handlers::Ruby::ModuleHandler:
[error]: in app/controllers/filters/quizzes.rb:19:

19: module Filters::Quizzes
[error]: NoMethodError: undefined method length' for nil:NilClass [error]: Stack trace: /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:210:inon_ignored_nl'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:50:in parse'     /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:50:inparse'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:15:in parse'     /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:439:inparse'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:44:in `block in parse'

Client app 'canvas_quizzes' was built successfully.
--> Creating ember app bundles
** Invoke js:bundle_ember_apps (first_time)
** Execute js:bundle_ember_apps
--> Pre-compiling ember handlebars templates
** Invoke jst:ember (first_time)
** Execute jst:ember
--> Pre-compiling handlebars templates
** Invoke jst:compile (first_time)
** Execute jst:compile
--> Compiling React JSX
** Invoke js:jsx (first_time)
** Execute js:jsx
--> Creating ember app bundles finished in 0.019525174999216688-->         Generating plugin extensions
** Invoke js:generate_extensions (first_time)

** Execute js:generate_extensions
--> Generating plugin extensions finished in 0.013264465998872765
--> Compiling CoffeeScript with 'coffee' binary
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-        lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
throw e
^

Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:460:18)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at bindings (/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object. (/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/c    ontextify.js:1:96)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_    modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
throw e
^

Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:460:18)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at bindings (/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_    modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object. (/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/c    ontextify.js:1:96)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_    modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
throw e
^

Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:460:18)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at bindings (/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_    modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object. (/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/gems/canvas_i18nliner/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/c    ontextify.js:1:96)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
[error]: Unhandled exception in YARD::Handlers::Ruby::ModuleHandler:
[error]: in app/controllers/filters/quiz_submissions.rb:19:

19: module Filters::QuizSubmissions
[error]: NoMethodError: undefined method length' for nil:NilClass     [error]: Stack trace: /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-    0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:210:inon_ignored_nl'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-    0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:50:in parse'     /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-    0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:50:inparse'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-    0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:15:in parse'     /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-    0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:439:inparse'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/yard-    0.8.7.6/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:44:in `block in parse'

--> Compiling React JSX finished in 11.014921448999303b
[warn]: @param tag has unknown parameter name: conversations 
in file app/controllers/quizzes/quiz_submission_users_controller.rb'     near line 139 ⌏ Generating /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/public/doc/api/all_resources.html.....................................    ............................⌌ Generating /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/public/doc/api/all_resources.html.....................................    ............................⌍ Generating /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-    lms/public/doc/api/all_resources.html.....................................    ............................⌎ Generating     lms/public/doc/api/all_resources.html.....................................    ............................Files: 94 Modules: 0 ( 0 undocumented)     Classes: 93 ( 30 undocumented) Constants: 0 ( 0 undocumented) Methods: 416     ( 7 undocumented) 92.73% documented API Documentation successfully     generated in public/doc/api See public/doc/api/index.html --> Finished:     'Generate documentation [yardoc]' in 40.264044159999685 rake aborted!     Undumpable Exception -- #<EOFError: end of file reached>     /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-    1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:63:inwork'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:280:in block (4 levels) in work_in_processes' /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:447:inwith_instrumentation'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:279:in block (3 levels) in work_in_processes' /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:273:inloop'
/home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:273:in block (2 levels) in work_in_processes' /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel-1.4.1/lib/parallel.rb:138:inblock (2 levels) in in_threads'
Tasks: TOP => canvas:compile_assets
```

### when I am trying to "node-gyp rebuild" I am getting following error:-

```
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /home/nsgill/projects/canvas-lms) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
```

### gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1

I tried all possible solutions. I have tried this with different versions of npm but facing the same issue.

Please let me know if you have any solution.